# Can i call cloud run and pass it an argument?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I know that cloud run will call a docker run command. What i want to do is call cloud run (docker run) and pass it an argument (image/video). 
My scenario is make a cloud run call from a flutter app, and pass an argument containing an image/video that the docker run will perform an analysis on. So ideally it would be something like

`docker run analysis.py mediafile.jpeg`

where `analysis.py` is the entrypoint and `mediafile.jpeg` is the argument.

Currently, I do not know how to create the cloud run function that can take an argument like described above. If anyone knows, please explain how.

Would a better alternative be to upload the media file to a database (firebase), then just call cloud run on the file in the database?

Any other suggestions welcome, thanks

Comment: How your flutter app will trigger your Cloud Run? Is the image/video is different at each run?

Comment: To provide Cloud Run with an argument as an HTTP Request query parameter. https://myservice.example.com?video=mediafile.jpeg. Then inside your container code process the request query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, I would recommend you to split your design in 2 parts :

1. First upload your media in Google Cloud Storage (or Firebase Cloud
   Storage)
2. Then, execute on Cloud Run or Firebase Cloud Function the
   job which will treat your media.

It's a good practice. Your design will be scalable, and keep simple to maintain.

Note that a [Firebase Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) can be triggered after a new file is uploaded on Cloud Storage.